# Обновление кэша

Tags: html, meta

Как заставить браузер обновить кэш сайта у всех пользователей сайта и не использовать кэш созданный до сегодняшнего дня?

Comment: Откройте страницу в режиме инкогнито, на мобиле тоже сработает.

Comment: Комментарий ниже тоже для Вас

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Дополните вопрос, опишите проблему более детально, приведите ваши попытки решения, добавьте в вопрос ваш [mcve]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Если клиент закешировал ресурсы, то он даже не будет пытаться их по-новой запрашивать.

Клиент может с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> обновить кэш, например. Но с серверной стороны это нельзя сделать для **всех** пользователей.

Или можно обновить сайт, заменив ссылки, к примеру, добавив левый параметр, чтоб браузер постучался к серверу за новыми ресурсами. Если ссылка на css была **mysite.com/css/kek.css** заменить на **mysite.com/css/kek.css?clearmeboi=1**

Comment: А meta тегов не существует, которые могут браузеру приказать обновить кэш?

Comment: @ДенисНебесный есть `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`, но оно не сработает, если контент **уже** закеширован.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте комбинацию:

```
CTRL + F5
```

Comment: Вы внимание на теги HTML и meta внимание не обратили? Кэш должен обновиться у всех

Comment: @ДенисНебесный что значит "обновиться у всех"?

Comment: Браузер должен удалить старый кэш сайта у всех пользователей сайта и внести новые данные в кэш